# How to highlight text and paste in place with Python keyboard

Tags: python, windows, keyboard-python

I am trying to understand the behavior I am seeing from running my script below and how I can get my desired outcome. Basically I'm using keyboard.add_word_listener() to run a function when the string "test" is typed. It ***should*** select the tab trigger key plus the "test" text and then copy it, and then replace it with bbbb  and then the copied text.

But if you look at the gif, it doesn't highlight the text. The "bbbb" gets inserted to the left of the "test" text. But it should have replaced the "test" text since it sends ctrl+shift+left which should select the previously entered text. The strange thing is the text still gets copied to the clipboard even though it doesn't look  like it got selected. And for some reason it gets pasted in a separate line in the beginning. I don't understand how that is possible. It works on macOS but not Windows.

I also tried replacing `ctrl+shift+left,ctrl+shift+left` with `shift+home` but the result is the same.

[image]

The script:

```
import keyboard 
import time

def test():
    keyboard.send("ctrl+shift+left,ctrl+shift+left")
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.send("ctrl+c")
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.send("b,b,b,b")
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.send("ctrl+v")

keyboard.add_word_listener("test",test,['tab'],False,1)

keyboard.wait()
```

Comment: Is that Sublime Text? Notepad and other plain text editors should behave the same; test with a few of those to rule out specific Sublime Text (mis)behavior.

Comment: @usr2564301 That was Visual Studio Code. I just tried it with Notepad++ and Notepad and it was almost the same except the pasted string (the last ctrl+v) showed up in the next line instead of being inserted into the first line. Which is even more confusing. I would expect it to paste between the bbbb and test.

Comment: But I still don't understand why "test" wasn't selected/highlighted even though it was copied into the clipboard by ctrl+c. There was no visual indication that it was highlighted.

Comment: It might just be an issue with the keyboard library

Comment: @KodosJohnson Just so you know, I've tried to debug your code last night, and found the same result. However, nothing was actually being copied when I tested it. Whatever already was in my clipboard was the thing that was pasted each time.

Answer (score 0):

I've been scratching my head about why this doesn't work for a while now and I've found a way to make it work.

When you call `keyboard.send` that method parses the given hotkeys, and tries to send a `scan_code` for each key that you've specified.

It parses the keys via the `keyboard.parse_hotkey` method. If we call that method ourselves, we can see what codes we get back:

```
>>> keyboard.parse_hotkey("ctrl+shift+left")
(((29, 57373), (42, 54), (75,)),)
```

Here we can see that both `ctrl` and `shift` has two codes, each for their right/left counterparts.

As you've discovered as well as me, is if you try to call a hotkey like `shift+home` the button-combination *seems* to be working correctly, because your position on the document seems to change. However, it seems like the way (at least on my end) the system handles the calls to `shift` doesn't work when you call just one of the `shift` codes.

We can change the hotkey to include both of the codes by calling them individually in the hotkey:

```
>>> keyboard.parse_hotkey("ctrl+right shift+left shift+left")
(((29, 57373), (54,), (42,), (75,)),)
```

If we update your code, to include the above hotkey instead, we can see that the expected behavior is happening:

```
import keyboard
def test():
    keyboard.send("ctrl+right shift+left shift+left")
    keyboard.send("ctrl+c")
    keyboard.send("b,b,b,b")
    keyboard.send("ctrl+v")

keyboard.add_word_listener("test", test, ['tab'], False, 1)
keyboard.wait()
```

At the time of writing I don't really know exactly *why* the above code works while your original code doesn't.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your code but it didn't seem like it selected the "test" trigger word. Ideally it would select the "test" trigger word and copy it. So when I type "test" and press tab, I should see "bbbbtest" but I am seeing "testbbbb" with a tab at the end.

Comment: @KodosJohnson I cannot replicate the behavior you've explained with my code. The result of the above code is always `'bbbbtest\t'` on my side, with `'test\t'` being the contents of the clipboard. Are you sure that it's the actual code that's messing up here? I found that VS-code didn't behave _at_ _all_ the same as Notepad++ or regular notepad, and added it's own newlines and replaced input based on what other files I had open.

Comment: @KodosJohnson I also suspect an [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here. Could you please expand on what the "end goal" of this is?